# what's the best way to add a class to the div with a class of post every 4 seconds using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's the best way to add a class to the div with a class of post every 4 seconds using jquery?

```
<div class="34 post">
<img width="311" height="417" src="#" class="#" alt="newspapers" />
<h2><a href="#">Headline News Part 2</a></h2>
<p>testing new content</p>
</div>

<div class="9 post">
<img width="311" height="417" src="#" class="#" alt="newspapers" />
<h2><a href="#">Headline News Part 2</a></h2>
<p>testing new content</p>
</div>

<div class="6 post">
<img width="311" height="417" src="#" class="#" alt="newspapers" />
<h2><a href="#">Headline News Part 2</a></h2>
<p>testing new content</p>
</div>
```

so i want the first to have a class of "display" then after 4 seconds, i want to remove the class on that one and add it to the second one. and then after 4 more seconds, remove it from the second and add it to the third. when it gets to the end it loops back around.

Comment: look into `setInterval` and `setTimeout` and create a function.

Answer (score 3):

```
var $postDivs = $('div.post'), // assuming these won't change
    i = -1,
    CLASS_NAME = 'foo';

setInterval(function () {
    $postDivs.eq(i).removeClass(CLASS_NAME);
    i = (i+1) % $postDivs.length;
    $postDivs.eq(i).addClass(CLASS_NAME);
}, 4000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/k2sJy/

Comment: oooo that's good! exceeeeeept it takes 4 seconds to start... the first div has to have the class there when the page loads

Comment: @KeganQuimby so put that into the markup. It's rather silly to not generate the markup you want to show when the page first loads, with this sort of thing. Anyway, if you absolutely insist on doing it with JS: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/YyNfn/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a simple infinite rotation of news items, you may try [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) for doing this.